# update records rank with laravel query builder

Tags: jquery, mysql, laravel

So I'm using laravel 5.8 an I have the following table named `tasks`

```
id |  name  | rank
------------------
 1 | task 1 |  4
------------------
 2 | task 2 |  3
------------------
 3 | task 3 |  2
------------------
 4 | task 4 |  1
```

And when I want to display this tasks I sort them ordredBy `rank` column (which is `unique` column) and if I want to change the rank for one task I need to update all tasks rank

I wanted to use this query:

```
UPDATE   tasks
JOIN     (SELECT    t.id,
                @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
      FROM      tasks t
      JOIN      (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
      ORDER BY  t.rank DESC
     ) ranks ON (ranks.id = tasks.id)
```

SET      taks.rank = ranks.rank;

so I made the select part from the query:

```
DB::table('tasks ta')
        ->select(DB::raw('ta.id, @curRank := @curRank + 1 as rank'))
        ->crossJoin(DB::raw('select @curRank : 0 as r'))
        ->orderBy('ta.rank', 'desc');
```

but i didn't figure out how to join update with the select statement in laravel query builder.

Comment: I don't see the need/purpose for any @variables here.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need to update all ranks, just update between the **currentRank** and **expectedRank**.

Example: Let say you want to update rank from task 1, from rank 4 to rank 2. You just move the rank between the currentRank and expectedRank

```
$expectedRank = 2;
$id = 1;
$task = Task::find($id);

// check if $task->rank != $expectedRank then do this query
$ids = Task::whereBetween('rank', [min($task->rank, $expectedRank), max($task->rank, $expectedRank)])
           ->where("id", "!=", $task->id)
           ->orderBy("rank")
           ->pluck("id");
$task->rank = $expectedRank;
$task->save();

$updates = Task::whereIn("id", $ids)
               ->update([
                  'rank'=> $task->rank > $expectedRank ? DB::raw('rank+1') : DB::raw('rank-1')
               ]);
```

Comment: I am sorry for my late internet problem :(, and thank you for helping me through this.. I tried something like that before but the problem is that the `rank` column is `unique` column and if I run this sort of logic I will end up with duplicate entry constraint.. So if I do the following: update the current task rank with symbole or something and then update all other tasks and then update (for the second time) the current task with the appropriate rank.. is it bad practice?

Comment: I thought it's bad. because if you did like that, you will do 3 update transaction process to your database, I thought it can be solved with do something tricky in `$updates`, try using if else condition in the update to check whether it's the ID u want to update or not. and remove `where("id", "!=", $task->id)`